# Convert character in format YEARQT to a quarterly "date" in R

Tags: r, zoo, as.date, tsibble

| Date |
| --- |
| 1960Q1 |
| 1960Q2 |
| 1960Q3 |
| 1960Q4 |
| 1961Q1 |
| 1961Q2 |

I have the following data.frame. I am trying to put this first column into a tsibble.
Now I have a problem. How can I switch to a date so that it can be read as a quarter.

I tried `zoo` using

```r
DATA.QTR <- DATA.QTR %>%   mutate(QUARTER = as.Date(as.yearqtr(Date, "%Y %Q")))
```

but it's not reading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it! The format needs to be sligthly adapted.

`%YQ%q`: `%Y` stands for the year, `Q` stands for the Q in your inital format and `%q` stands for the quarter.

**Code**

```
library(zoo)

DATA.QTR <- DATA.QTR %>% mutate(QUARTER = as.Date(as.yearqtr(format(Date), "%YQ%q")))
```

**Output**

```
> DATA.QTR
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Date   QUARTER   
  <chr>  <date>    
1 1960Q1 1960-01-01
2 1960Q2 1960-04-01
3 1960Q3 1960-07-01
4 1960Q4 1960-10-01
5 1961Q1 1961-01-01
6 1961Q2 1961-04-01
```

**Data**

```
DATA.QTR <- structure(list(Date = c("1960Q1", "1960Q2", "1960Q3", "1960Q4", 
                                    "1961Q1", "1961Q2")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                    ), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks man. So the Q in "%YQ%q", is to tell R there is no space in the chr string?

Comment: @Note No, the Q is the one you provided in your vector, for example `1960Q1`. If there were a whitespace before the Q, for example `1960 Q1`, you would need to adjust to `"%Y Q%q"`.